# Can we access a deallocated memory?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

*I noticed that the local variables of a function are getting same memory all the time, so I tried to access the memory after returning from the function.*
(I tried to access the deallocted memory)

**1st attempt:**
In this first code I returned the address of local variable(also got a warning from compiler) then when I tried to access this memory in
main, program stops due to segmentation fault.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int * fun()
{
    int a;
    printf("Address of a is %p\n",&a);
    printf("Value of a is %d\n",a);
    return &a;
}
int main()
{
    int *p;
    p=fun();
    *p=100;//Segmentation fault: program stops execution at this line 
           // which can be verified as the printf statement in next line doesn't execute
    printf("Hi");
    fun();
}
```

**Output:**
testC.c:26:12: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
return &a;
^~

Address of a is 000000000061FDDC

Value of a is 0

**2nd attempt:**
Now I tried the same thing but with a little twist that instead of returning address directly I returned it with the help of an extra pointer and in this case I did not get any warning from compiler and I successfully access a deallocated memory in main by putting value 100 at that address which can be seen during next function call.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int * fun()
{
    int a,*p;
    printf("Address of a is %p \nAddress of p is %p\n",&a,&p);
    printf("Value of a is %d\n",a);
    p=&a;
    return p;
}
int main()
{
    int *p;
    p=fun();
    *p=100;//Segmentation fault: program doesn't stop here
           //compiler is not able to catch this fault and we access a deallocated memory
           //and successfully insert 100 at a deallocated memory, which we can see in next fun() call.
    fun();
}
```

**Output:**

Address of a is 000000000061FDDC

Address of p is 000000000061FDD0

Value of a is 0

Address of a is 000000000061FDDC

Address of p is 000000000061FDD0

Value of a is 100

**Can someone please explain how is this possible to access a deallocated memory like this?**

Comment: The behavior is undefined. It is nondeterminant. You are lucky if you are able to write to the address, but this is not guaranteed at all

Comment: Suggestion: flush the output buffer after the `printf()` ... either explicitly with `fflush(stdout);` or implicitly (assuming line-buffered output) by terminating the output with a newline `printf("Hi!\n");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes, undefined behaviour works as you may expect - that is, after all, one of the gazillion things it could do, and is its most insidious feature - from a programmer perspective, it would be better if it crashed every time with an informative message (this would, however, almost certainly slow C down enough that people would clamour for the old behaviour).

In ***no*** way does the fact it *may* work make it a good idea since it may also do one of the *other* gazillion-minus-one things, such as forming a miniature black hole which swallows half your house before evaporating, or erasing your storage devices while playing the file `derisive_laughter.mp3` :-)

The details can be found in (for C11) `6.2.4 Storage durations of objects`:

> The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists, has a constant address, and retains its last-stored value throughout its lifetime. ***If an object is referred to outside of its lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.***

Your `a` variable is an automatic one, as per that same section:

> An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without the storage-class specifier static has automatic storage duration
>
> For such an object that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way.

Since the lifetime of that `a` variable ceases at the end of `fun()`, the pointer to it becomes indeterminate, and this is covered in `6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators`:

> If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary `*` operator is undefined.

That section references the following footnote:

> Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary `*` operator are a null pointer, an address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and ***the address of an object after the end of its lifetime.***