# Why is the pointer giving me this value?

Tags: c, pointers

I was studying for a test with the following question with the given output :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *const p = &i;
    foo(&p);
    printf("%d\n", *p);
}
void foo(int **p)
{
    int j = 11;
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d\n", **p);
}
```

> **Output : 11 11**

I understand that the address of `*p` pointing to int `i` is passed to the function `foo`. Here, `**p` is a pointer pointing to `*p`, where `*p` points to `int i`.
In the function, `**p` pointer changes and points to `int j`, and the first `printf` is called and 11 is printed.

What I don't understand is the output from the 2nd `printf` function. Why is it printing 11, when it should be 10? I've checked and the value of `int i` and it did not change, so shouldn't dereferencing `*p` give 10 and not 11.

Can someone explain to me the logic behind what is happening and why is it happening?

Comment: " Why is it printing 11, when it should be 10?" Because you explicitly assigned the pointer elsewhere: `*p = &j;`.

Comment: @Lundin actually `*p = &j;` points to a local variable so the behavior is undefined

Comment: [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Comment: the second print is undefined, you try to access the dealoocated variable - j(it "dies" after the end of foo), usually what will happen is that you will try to access the memory so that's why you get 11, but it is undefined, so everything can happen, you can read more about accessing deallocated memory here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59498290/can-we-access-a-deallocated-memory

Comment: Just to mention `const` keyword preventing you from modifying the value only by assignements, you can still set to a new value with the memory address of the `const` variable, like you just did it in your code. Most complier should give you a warning in this case since you're discarding the `const` qualifier when you passed the address of `int *const p` to `int **p` instead of `int * const* p`. Of course in this case you would get an error on `*p = &j` since `*p` became read only.

Answer (score 0):

First you asign p the address of i and you input the address of p to the function foo and inside the foo function the the value of p becomes what every the value in j (*p = &j). When the memory address changes in the foo function you are not changing it back.

NOTE: There the variable p is not passed by value, It is passed to the function by reference. So any change you do to the p variable inside the foo function will affect the p variable inside the main function because they have the same memory address

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
*p = &j;
```

makes the original variable

```
int *const p
```

point to the address of the local variable

```
int j
```

After foo is called, that local variable j has since been deallocated from the stack, but p is still pointing to that same stack location which still has that value of 11.  So you are illegally accessing deallocated stack memory but it just happens to remain the value of 11.  So it is printed a second time.

Comment: the correct term would be "out of scope" and when the scope of a variable ends, accessing it invokes UB